# How to hide and show a CKEditor using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, ckeditor

The following code should allow to hide/show the CKEditor form

```
<a onClick="$('#form1').hide();">Hide</a>
<a onClick="$('#form1').show();">Show</a>
<form action="sample_posteddata.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">blabla</textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript"> CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' ); </script>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

However, this code works fine on Chrome but on Firefox, once I have toggled once the editor (one 'hide' click followed by one 'show' click) , it becomes not editable !!

How can I make it work on every browser?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to have a real workaround.

See [here](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=19497) for more info. The only solution is to wait for CKEditor new version 3.4.

Answer (score 3):

Solution is:

```
// Hide form
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy();
$('#form1').hide();
//Show form
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {height: "220px", skin: "v2"});
$('#form1').show();
```

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer at http://dizkover.com/post/67/how-to-show-hide-ckeditor-using-jquery-ckeditor-tip

So basically, you have to destory the CKEditor instance first by doing the ff:

```
if(typeof CKEDITOR.instances['element_name'] != 'undefined') {
    CKEDITOR.instances['element_name'].updateElement();
    CKEDITOR.instances['element_name'].destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this might help you out:

http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/544

In the report I linked to they show trying something like this:

```
if (frames[0]) {
  frames[0].FCK.EditingArea.MakeEditable();
}
```

Comment: I'll try your suggestion...but the bug you have likned it is marked as FIXED and I am using last version of CKEditor.

Comment: I tried it but itis not working (FCK is not used anymore in CKEditor version 3.X). Do you have another idea?

Comment: Do you have a site that I can test on?

Comment: You can download an example here : http://www.4shared.com/file/5bQxbrEl/ckeditor_samples.html. Just unzip and open the html file. Click hide/show => it will not work on FF

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="container">            
    <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
<p>
    <input type="button" value="jQuery Hide" onclick="$('#container').hide('fast');" />
    <input type="button" value="jQuery Show" onclick="$('#container').show('fast');" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapped it in a div eg : `<div id="fckz"> <form >...</form> </div>`
and make the hide show on the div .

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div[id*='cke_editor']").hide();

$("div[id*='cke_editor']").show();
```

For my CkEditor 4