# Ckeditor disabled after hide (empty iframe)

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have replaced a textarea with:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('content');
```

this is the html:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
</div>
```

however, if I hide the div with

```
$('#mydiv').hide();
```

and then

```
$('#mydiv').show();
```

the ckeditor area is no more editable: it seems that the iframe used by ckeditor is empty... why?

this is the js code:

```
$('#contents > div').eq(oldActiveIndex).hide('drop', {direction: "left"}, 1000, function() {
    var newActiveIndex = $('nav.multipage a.active').index();
    $('#contents > div').eq(newActiveIndex).show('drop', {direction: "right"}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: is it not working on all browsers like chrome, ie or firefox? or it is  limited to only one like FF? See link next http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269456/how-to-hide-and-show-a-ckeditor-using-jquery

Comment: no it's now working on all the browser. I have updated my post with the code that I use

Comment: it seems that if i do a normal hide() or show(), it works... the problem is with the animation...

Comment: I cannot confirm this. Can you provide us a jsFiddle?